# Any Way to Disable JSHint for .jsx Files (Ideally in WebStorm)

Tags: webstorm, jshint, reactjs

I know (from another Stack Overflow question) that I can disable JSHint parsing of parts of my files by adding certain directives, such as the following (not actual JSHint code):

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        // magic directive start!
        return <input/>
        // magic directive end!
    }
```

But the thing is, I really don't want to clutter up all of my .jsx files with such directives; I'd prefer to simply tell JSHint "just skip any file with a .jsx" extension.

However, I haven't been able to find a way to specify that through a `.jshintrc` or `package.json` file. Am I just missing the relevant option, or is there really no way to do this?

P.S. I mainly use JSHint through WebStorm, so if JSHint has no way to ignore .jsx files, but WebStorm does, that would be helpful too.

Comment: **1)** Define custom **Scope** that would include only desired files (and optionally exclude unwanted) .. or that it would include only all unwanted ones **2)** configure JSHint inspection -- it allows to enable/disable it based on scope. **3)** Note that it would be applied to whole file and not just parts of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) which is supported by [Webstorm](https://github.com/idok/eslint-plugin) and can handle jsx files just fine. ESLint does what JSHint does and then some.

You could even add linting rules to your JSX via a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react).